# TypeScript & runtime type-checking, simple solution in 2020

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, babeljs, typescript2.0

As we all know, TypeScript type-checks only at compile-time.

There are couple of existing approaches to add runtime checks, such as [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts), but I'm left to wonder if there is a simpler way.

For example a Babel plugin that would transpile this:

```js
type Todo = {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

const resp = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");

const data = await resp.json();

assert(data typeof Todo);
```

to that:

```js
const __TodoType = {
  userId: Number;
  id: Number;
  title: String;
  completed: Boolean;
};
const __isTodoType = obj => (
  obj &&
  obj.constructor === Object &&
  Object.keys(obj).length === Object.keys(__TodoType).length &&
  Object.entries(obj)
    .every(([prop, val]) =>
      __TodoType[prop] && val &&
      __TodoType[prop] === val.constructor)
);

const resp = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");

const data = await resp.json();

assert(__isTodoType(data));
```

This would be a super simple solution and would cover many (if not most) uses cases. AFAICT, this would be enough for asserting serialization / data fetching.

Has someone managed to build such Babel plugin?

**Edit** - I know the existing libraries such as io-ts but I'm looking for something much simpler. The Babel Plugin I'm showcasing is vastly simpler (from the perspective of the plugin user) than anything else I've seen so far. I'm not sure why this hasn't been done before.

Comment: I don't think this is as simple as you think. How do you handle errors? False positives? False negatives? What about nested data, does it generate the assertions over and over? Ditto for modules. Effect on bundle size/bandwidth? It's not that these aren't solvable, but some of them require deciding between tradeoffs and that's even harder to do well.

Comment: I agree that, from the perspective of implementing such Babel plugin it's not simple. But, from the perspective of the plugin user, this would be super simple: just add `obj typeof MyType` and "bam" you have a run-time check :-).

Comment: Can you explain, what you understand by "simple"? There are quite a few solutions out there -  and io-ts *is* in some way rel. simple to use. Do you want a code generator without runtime dependencies, use TS compiler API, etc. Babel probably can't do that, as the typescript preset just strips off the types and does not process them.

Comment: If the example scenario (flat objects with basic properties) is all that you care about, you can just write the const instead of the type and the derive the type from it.

Comment: I've created an experimental package called `ts-data-checker` that uses TypeScript language service to check types at runtime: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-data-checker

Comment: Check out https://typescript-rtti.org/

Answer (score 7):

I was frustrated by this as well and ended up writing my own type guard generator called ‛ts-type-checked‛ available as an [NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-type-checked). It is a TypeScript transform that generates type guards based on your types.

Answer (score -1):

Give [typescript-runtime-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-runtime-types/v/1.0.0) a try. I don't know how or if this works with Babel, but there is a small section on using it with Webpack and awesome-typescript-loader. I think it does what you're looking for, although the only examples it shows are with interfaces, which may mean you aren't allowed to nest types or use `&` or `|` or `Pick` or other complex type annotations. If that's true, you will just need to use io-ts.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know any cool tool to do that automatically but I can tell you what I use to validate types on runtime: AJV - https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv

It's not ideal because you need to generate your json schemas for each type, but you can automate that with typescript-json-schema (https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema#readme)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

TySheMo https://github.com/tangshuang/tyshemo

> A javascript runtime data type checking system ...

I have been using this library for front-end `api guarding`

Sometimes back-end gives me a `null` or an empty object `{}` breaking down the page with `... cannot read property xxx of null ...`

Write an `interceptor` for api's responses using this, you can capture the dirty data no matter how deep the data structure of `res` is

Personally, I have revised the source code of `TySheMo` and it really is a great piece of work

Answer (score -3):

Typescript's [`instanceof` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) checks the constructor function, but I don't think it checks all the keys as well. Still, in most cases, it should be enough.

Working with external API, you can use [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) package for more detailed validation, and [class-transformer-validator](https://github.com/MichalLytek/class-transformer-validator) if you want to transform plain objects (for example, parsed from JSON) to your classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm afraid `instanceof` doesn't type check the whole structure of the data, e.g. data coming from an API. As for `class-validator` and `class-transformer-validator`, although these do provide a solution to a certain degree, they don't re-use my TypeScript types to do validation which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -3):

I'm using [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/Type.md). You only need to write once for type and runtime checking.